# What does MR version stand for?

Tags: android, version, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, abbreviation

Today I got Android ICS update. The system shows version "Ice Cream Sandwich MR1". I know alpha, beta, rc, rtm, etc. but I was wandering what **MR** stands for.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think it means Maintenance Release 1.

Source: I just heard it somewhere on a different application using MR in their version.

Comment: An example from the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.3.4.html) which confirms it: *"Android 2.3.4 (GINGERBREAD_MR1) is a maintenance release"*.

Answer (score 8):

> mr = "maintenance release", fr = "factory rom".
>
> JBQ

(via ["Kernel suffixes,"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-building/5SKMilqvXys/LgbF576GF-YJ) Android Building mailing list)

JBQ is a former tech lead of the Android Open Source Project.

Answer (score 2):

It could also mean Manufacturer's Release. As in this is the release your Manufacturer did, in this case Google. Motorola would have a completely different MR1 release in this case.

Answer (score 1):

MR is maintenance release while SMR is Security maintenance release.
To keep the phone secure and bug free, ODMs generally provide updates.